# Circuit review: Switch/monitor 12V devices using a USB-connected microcontroller

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, circuit-protection, review

I've designed a board to allow my desktop computer to switch external USB hard drives on and off.  I don't have a huge amount of experience with circuits like this one so I'd like to get some feedback on the design before I build it.

The circuit is controlled by a [Teensy 3.1](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensy31.html) microcontroller board connected to the host (and powered) via USB.  Each drive's USB connection is always attached to the host and its power supply is switched using this circuit.  Each drive has its own 12V 2A power supply.  Up to 5 drives can be controlled; each has its own essentially identical switch/monitor sub-circuit (described below).  The board itself will be a double-sided home-etched board with ~2oz copper (0.10mm) on each side; vias are "plated" with 0.5mm bus wire soldered on each side.  I am not using a ground plane.  I am going to be hand soldering everything.

**Common ground**
I've connected the grounds for the Teensy (and thus USB) and each drive.  The common ground trace (0.05") runs in a linear U shape on the bottom layer connecting to the Teensy's ground at one end with short (<1cm) spurs to each component.

**12V power**
The larger (0.05") traces on the top of the board carry the 12V power for each drive.  The power supplies are rated at 2A each and typical current is 0.8A peaking briefly at ~1.8A during drive spin-up.  `12V_IN_1` is connected to the power supply's 12V rail and `12V_OUT_1` is connected to the hard drive's 12V input.  Ground is passed through from the power supply to the drive on `GND_IN_1` and `GND_OUT_1` and connects through a via to the board's ground rail.

**Fusing**
Each drive is protected by a 2A fast blow 5×20mm glass fuse (`F1`).  I'm using ones I have on hand.  They're designed for use in holders but I'll be surface mounting them.  I'll be monitoring the current through each circuit so I'll be able to cut power from software as well.

**Power switching**
Each drive's power is switched using a [TPS22810 load switch](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps22810-q1.pdf) (`IC_SW1`) with R<sub>on</sub> of 79mΩ.  The datasheet recommends a max current of 2A at 65C and max voltage of 18V.  The switch is controlled by an active-high pin (`ENABLE_1`) where high is between 1.2V and 18V.  This pin is connected directly to one of the Teensy's GPIOs.  I may pull this high using 10kΩ pullup to the +12V trace (`R7`) so that the 12V output defaults to being on.  Normally the Teensy turns the 12V output on by driving `ENABLE_1` high (3.3V) and off by driving it low (0V).

**Current monitoring**
The switched output flows through a [0.01Ω current sense resistor](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/303/ohmite_07222019_L4t_-1623139.pdf) (`CR1`) with a Kelvin connection to a [NCS199A2R shunt monitor](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/NCS199A1R-D-1812815.pdf) (`IC_CS1`) with 100V/V output.  The power supply for this chip is the Teensy's 3.3V rail.  The chip's output is connected to a [MCP3008 ADC](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/21295b-72710.pdf) via `CSENSE_1`.  The ADC is also powered by the Teensy's 3.3V rail and connected to it via a non-isolated SPI bus.

**Status LED**
Each drive has a status [LED](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/90/data-sheet-JSeries-2835-3v-1666992.pdf) (`D1`, V<sub>f</sub>=2.95V).  It is powered from the drive's 12V rail via `R1` (either 100Ω or 220Ω) and is controlled by an N-channel MOSFET (`Q1`).  The MOSFET's gate is connected directly to a Teensy PWM-capable GPIO pin via `LED_1` and driven to 3.3V for on and 0V for off.  The LED will reside off-board and connect to the two pads between `R1` and `Q1`.

Does anything about this circuit seem dangerous or dubious?  I'm rather concerned about letting the magic smoke out.

[image: Schematic]

[image: Board]
Board layout for a single channel.
Portions of adjacent channels included to show clearance.
Grid spacing 0.1 inch